# "Руки, теперь украшенные ногтями с траурной каёмкой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Рассказывает: "Опомнился я уже на коленях, на поляне аканта, на вилле
>   Челимонтана. Рыл землю руками", – и он продемонстрировал свои красивые
>   руки, теперь украшенные ногтями с траурной каёмкой.

Как, сохранив в неприкосновенности все слова, выкарабкаться из проблемы?

Или проблема мне только мнится? О_о

Comment: ...продемонстрировал свои красивые руки, теперь с ногтями украшенными траурной каёмкой.

Comment: Тогда уж так: *...продемонстрировал свои красивые руки - теперь с ногтями, украшенными траурной каёмкой*.

Comment: Да, но у меня тогда близко два разновекторнонаправленных тире будут...

Comment: Обычный причастный оборот, все вполне нормально.

Comment: _... - ногти на них теперь были украшены..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что возможно написать так. Для акцента — красивые руки и траурная кайма одновременно — просится тире.

*...и он продемонстрировал свои красивые руки — с ногтями, теперь украшенными* [или украшенными теперь] *траурной каёмкой.*

Или так:
*...красивые руки, теперь под ногтями украшенные траурной каёмкой.*
*...красивые руки, теперь украшенные траурной каёмкой под ногтями.*

P. S. Не вижу всего контекста, но мне думается, что прямая речь должна быть оформлена таким образом.
— ...Рыл землю руками. [точка] — И [прописная] он продемонстрировал свои красивые...

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что в исходном варианте руки когда-то были без ногтей -  "а теперь и с ногтями..." :) .

Comment: Ага, Сашко, это-то меня и смутило, но до сознанья не добралось. )))